# How to filter on a field for a set of values

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model called **products**. The **category** belongs to this model. Now I can filter for this section field with a value. Actually I wanted to filter by **multiple values** ​​for the **same field**

Example: If I filter with **phone** (is a category) it works
But for this section field, I need to filter by **phone** and **cases**

## filter

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category',
                  'min_price', 'max_price'
                  ]
```

## View

```
class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

How do I do that?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

define a **`CharFilter`** and specify the **`lookup_expr`** argument,

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
    category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'min_price', 'max_price']
```

Answer (score -1):

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

```
first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
year_joined = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year')
year_joined__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year__gt')
year_joined__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year__lt')
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', ]
```